# Interaction between multiple select boxes

Tags: angularjs

I am new to Angular.js and have a design question.

I have three multi-select boxes on a page, one for Products, one for Users, and one for Groups.
On page load, Products shows all Products, Users shows all Users, and Groups shows all Groups.
When the user chooses one or more Products, Users and Groups should each refresh to show only those users/groups that have used the Product.

What is the Angular way to design the interaction between these select boxes?

My first approach is:

- Each select is fed from an $http.get() to fill it
- When user taps on a Product, listen to that select (with jQuery on()?), construct the $http.get() request, and update the models. This will update the select boxes for Users and Groups.

This feels very... un-Angular. Suggestions on how to improve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bind each select to a model and use ng-change to listen. Don't forget to set ng-options on your select, this will automatically bind your secondary select box when the get returns:

HTML:

```
<select ng-model="product" ng-change="productChanged()" ng-options="p.name for p in products"></select>
<select ng-model="user" ng-options="u.name for u in users"></select>
```

Controller:

```
    $scope.productChanged = function(){
        //$scope.product has your selected item in it.
        $scope.users = $http.get(...)
    }
```

See the documentation on select for a full explanation of ng-options: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:select

Comment: You can also watch the changing value of a variable in scope like so: scope.$watch('product', function() {
     $http.get(...)
   }); but this will fire whenever the underlying model changes, which is different in important ways from when the user changes the select box.

Comment: Looks like the attribute is ng-change, not ng-changed. Can you correct your answer?

Answer (score 0):

I was just looking into this yesterday. Check out my jsfiddle I put together that uses a directive to handle everything. It keeps a list of the clicked objects id in an array.
http://jsfiddle.net/zargyle/t7kr8/

It's based on this html layout

```
<div ng-repeat="item in list" >
    <input type="checkbox" checkbox-group />
    <label>{{item.value}}</label>
</div>
```